# Linq: A query inside a field

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to write a nested query.

I have 3 objects:

```
public class Invoice
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<InvoiceDet> Details { get; set; }
}
public class InvoiceDet
{
  public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
  public int Quantity { get; set; }
  public int ArticleId { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to create the linq query as follows, but it throws an error:
"Linq To Entities exception does not recognize the method and cannot be translated into store expression"

```
var model = from i in db.Invoices
            select new
            {
               Id = i.Id,
               details = (from d in i.Details
                          from a in db.Articles.Where(a => a.Id == d.ArticleId)
                                           select new 
                                           {
                                               Id = a.Id,
                                               Description = a.Description,
                                               Total = a.Price * d.Quantity
                                           }).Distinct().ToList()
           };
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: LINQ to entities has to translate to SQL; so is very picky. Have you tried materializing the list before doing the sub query?

Comment: normally when I get a not supported exception, it tells me what method is the problem

Comment: I would also expect `InvoiceDet` to have an `InvoiceId`, to facilitate the 1 to many relationship

Comment: to make your linq easier to read in my opinion have you considered using `JOIN` instead of the many Selects

Comment: you are right Sam I sam, now I edited it

Comment: I'm pretty sure LINQ to Entities does not let you have any nested queries like that.

Comment: In your inner select statement, the property `a.Descripcion` does not match the spelling in the class definition you posted above (`Description`)

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to Entities, while similar looking to LINQ to Objects, is a fairly different beast. Entity Framework builds an expression tree from your query, which, when you first try to enumerate through the data, is translated to a SQL statement. Unfortunately, there are some things that Entity Framework cannot/does not translate to SQL, and one of those things is a nested query. It simply isn't designed to know what to do with

```
details = (from d in i.Details.....
```

You'll need to rewrite your query so it doesn't have a nested query like that.